# How can I determine a gaussian field for thresholding a distribution at each location of a grid?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, gaussian-process, spatial, pattern-recognition

Suppose $X(u, v) \in R$ is a random variable at location $(u,v)$ of a grid $G \subset R^2$, and $X(u,v)$ can be expectedly decomposed into two components with a unknown threshold $t(u,v)$ with $t(u,v) \geq 0$, one representing background and the other anomaly. Besides, $t(u,v)$ is expected to be spatially correlated, which decays as distance among cells.

I assume that $t(u,v)$ is a Gaussian field. The objective is to determine the threshold distribution $t(u,v), (u,v)\in G$ given the distribution of $X(u, v)$, or a 3-dimensional array $x(u,v,l), l=1,2,...,n$. Is there any idea that can solve the parameters of Gaussian field $t(u,v)$, i.e. $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ using the data $x(u,v,l)$?

My preliminary consideration is: for each location $(u, v)$, the expectation of $t(u,v)$ can be determined from clustering procedure, such as *k*-means, but we should also consider the constraint $t(u,v) \geq 0$. In addition, I have no idea about how to link this procedure to the estimation of parameters of Gaussian field, especially the covariance.

Perhaps I did not formulate the problem well since my major is not related to mathematics. Neither did I know what kind of issue it belongs to. Is there anyone who can give me help?

(1) How can I formulate the problem?

(2) What kind of issue it is, so I can read some papers.

Comment: Could you explain what a "link" to a "cluster criterion" might mean?

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I have reedited the question, @whuber.